# SQL Server trigger firing 3 times

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have set up the following audit trigger to create copies of the record changes into my change log (should we ever need to see what happened to our data). The problem is every time I update the record, it creates 3 records in my log table.

Below you can see the result set and my code I have been using.

[image: result set]

Code:

```
/*  ==Scripting Parameters==
    Source Server Version : SQL Server 2016 (13.0.4446)
    Source Database Engine Edition : Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition
    Source Database Engine Type : Standalone SQL Server

    Target Server Version : SQL Server 2017
    Target Database Engine Edition : Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition
    Target Database Engine Type : Standalone SQL Server
*/

USE [STONE_DB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_set_for_update_audit_fields]
ON [dbo].[permission_types]
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO STONE_DB_CHANGE_LOGS.dbo.permission_types_log ([permission_type_id], [business_process], [active], [created_at], [created_by], [change_type], [change_user], [change_at])
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            inserted.id, 
            inserted.[business_process], inserted.[active],
            inserted.[created_at], inserted.[created_by],
            'U', SYSTEM_USER, GETDATE()
        FROM 
            inserted
        WHERE 
            1 = 1
            AND inserted.[created_at] < getdate();

        UPDATE [dbo].[permission_types]
        SET updated_at = GETDATE(), updated_by = SYSTEM_USER
        FROM [dbo].[permission_types] 
        INNER JOIN inserted ON permission_types.id = inserted.id
        WHERE 1 = 1
          --AND permission_types.updated_at < getdate() 
        ;

        PRINT 'Record Updated'
END
```

Comment: are there same id present multiple times in permission_types table?

Comment: You create an on update trigger and then perform an update within the trigger... try to remove the update statement from the trigger...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent a database trigger from recursing

Check this solution

[How do I prevent a database trigger from recursing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529412/how-do-i-prevent-a-database-trigger-from-recursing)

Answer (score 1):

You should add at the begin of trigger code like this:

```
IF NOT UPDATE(business_process)
    RETURN;
```

More info: [UPDATE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

USE the following code to avoid nesting

IF((SELECT trigger_nestlevel() ) > 1)
RETURN