# How to do an insert in an update trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an `UPDATE` trigger that occurs when a record is inserted into a table but would like to create an `INSERT` at the same time the trigger is fired.

The original INSERT puts a record into the BatchQueue table and when this occurs the trigger is fired to update a second table [Call].

I want to be able to add a record in the BatchQueue table that is basically similar to the initial record being inserted but differs on the time columns and one other column. I could technically do it on the original insert but would need to do a WHEN or IF, for only when SFlags = 11

The original INSERT statement:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO BatchQueue (TimeToExecute, Operation, 
    Parameter,RuleID, FilterID, SFlags)
        SELECT @TimeToExecute, @Operation, @Parameter, @RuleID, @FilterID, 
        @SFlags FROM Call WHERE [ID]=@Parameter AND Active=0
               AND (OnlineCount>0 OR OnlineScreenCount>0 
       OR (Flags&POWER(2,26)=POWER(2,26)))  
 END
```

This is the insert I would like to do:

```
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[BatchQueue]
   VALUES(DateAdd(mi,2,getutcdate()),1,Call.ID,2,null,9,0,0,0)
   WHEN Call.SFlags = 11
END
```

The trigger statement:

```
BEGIN
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON
   UPDATE Call SET StoreReqCount = StoreReqCount + CallCount.actionCount
   FROM Call, (SELECT Parameter, [actionCount] = COUNT(*) FROM inserted 
   GROUP BY Parameter ) AS CallCount
   WHERE Call.ID = CallCount.Parameter
END
```

Can someone advise how best to do this? I hope I have clarified. To reiterate, either add the second INSERT to the first with the condition of SFlags=11 or do the insert with the trigger. Which is better?

EDIT:

Tried the following:

```
   SELECT @StoreActionID = [ID] FROM BatchQueue 
   WHERE Parameter=@Parameter AND RuleID=@RuleID AND 
    SFlags=@SFlags
   IF @StoreActionID IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN
     UPDATE BatchQueue SET FilterID = @FilterID WHERE [ID] = 
     @StoreActionID
   END
ELSE
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO BatchQueue (TimeToExecute, Operation, Parameter, 
      RuleID, FilterID, SFlags)
        SELECT @TimeToExecute, @Operation, @Parameter, @RuleID, 
     @FilterID, @SFlags FROM Call WHERE [ID]=@Parameter AND Active=0
               AND (OnlineCount>0 OR OnlineScreenCount>0 OR 
     (Flags&POWER(2,26)=POWER(2,26))) --bit26 indicates META-DATA-ONLY
END
-- ADDED ADDITIONAL INSERT TO INSERT ACTION BASED ON STOREFLAGS 
BEGIN
    IF @SFlags = 11
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO BatchQueue (TimeToExecute, Operation, Parameter, 
        RuleID, FilterID, SFlags)
        SELECT @TimeToExecute, @Operation, @Parameter, @RuleID, 
        @FilterID, 9 FROM Call WHERE [ID]=@Parameter AND Active=0
               AND (OnlineCount>0 OR OnlineScreenCount>0 OR 
        (Flags&POWER(2,26)=POWER(2,26))) --bit26 indicates META-DATA-ONLY
    END        
END
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you looking to modify your `INSERT INTO [dbo].[BatchQueue]` statement such that some of the values would come from `Call` table? If so, please specify the logic.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to restate the question more clearly

Comment: Are you looking to insert a second record (row) to BatchQueue when `Call.SFlags = 11`? or modify an existing record?

Comment: Add a second to row based on that condition. I have tried something but it did not work. will add in edit now.

Comment: you have two options: do it in the trigger but you need to make sure direct trigger recursion is disabled (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1529516/6305294) - could be problematic if other code depends on it.

Comment: I also notice that you use variables a lot, is your trigger written to process single row inserts only? (See this article: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2911/working-with-triggers/)

Comment: thanks Alex. Yes I just realized the cascade effects of triggers so a bit weary of the effect of changing it. Thanks for the links will review first. Yes it does do single row insert only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the good options you can take is write a stored procedure, and within the stored procedure include the original INSERT statement and then the special INSERT into same table as first INSERT. But, only execute the special INSERT if the first INSERT was successful.

Let the UPDATE happen through your existing trigger.  You don't want to disturb the trigger if its being used in production successfully.

Also,it would be good if you can wrap these two INSERTstatements within a transaction.

This will satisfy your requirement.

**Put following T-SQL code into your stored precedure**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRY

 Declare @insertedID int;

  --original INSERT
  INSERT INTO BatchQueue (TimeToExecute, Operation,
  Parameter, RuleID, FilterID, SFlags)
    SELECT
      @TimeToExecute,
      @Operation,
      @Parameter,
      @RuleID,
      @FilterID,
      @SFlags
    FROM Call
    WHERE [ID] = @Parameter
    AND Active = 0
    AND (OnlineCount > 0
    OR OnlineScreenCount > 0
    OR (Flags & POWER(2, 26) = POWER(2, 26));

  Set @insertedID = scope_identity() ;

  ---- INSERT if a row is successfully inserted
  IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
  BEGIN

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[BatchQueue]
      SELECT DATEADD(mi, 2, GETUTCDATE()), 1, @parameter, 2, NULL, 9, 0, 0, 0)  
      WHERE @SFlags = 11;

  END

  --commit tran
  IF @@trancount > 0
  BEGIN
    COMMIT TRAN
  END

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
  --get error details, which you can log to some table
  DECLARE @ErrorMessage nvarchar(4000);
  DECLARE @ErrorSeverity int;
  DECLARE @ErrorState int;

  SELECT
    @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
    @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
    @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

  --roll back tran
  IF @@trancount > 0
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN
  END

END CATCH
```

Comment: Thanks Sunil, will try this. How would you add an additional condition and change the insert to match the original insert rather than use all preset values? for example like I have in EDIT: If @SFlags = 11 I want to add if Call.onlinescreencount > 0

Comment: This does not seem to work and I think it has something to do with only allowing single row insert. I have updated the post to include the other statements in the stored procedure I did not include the first time that my impact this.

Comment: Where are these variables coming from - `@TimeToExecute, @Operation, @Parameter, @RuleID, @FilterID, @SFlags and @Parameter`? Are these input parameters to your stored procedure?

Comment: Also, can you use a simpler condition in place of `(Flags & POWER(2, 26) = POWER(2, 26)))`?

Comment: I have removed a closing parethesis in your bitwise operator condition. Try the query now.

Comment: The variables are coming from the table Call. Both statements are called from within the application (java code). These are input parameters.

Comment: Ok. Try the query now since I have removed a parenthesis.

Comment: I am understanding it now. Give me a few minutes to sort this out.

Comment: I changed the second insert to match the original insert to avoid having default values in the procedure. Please see my edit and thanks for your time with this. It only inserts the first record. No problem. Once the first insert happens, if the sflags = 11 then do the second insert.

Comment: In your query `(SELECT Parameter, [actionCount] = COUNT(*) FROM inserted 
   GROUP BY Parameter )` do you get only one record or multiple records when you group by paramater the inserted records?

Comment: I think the above complext query may not be needed. Instead just use `WHERE Call.ID = @Parameter` in UPDATE statement.

Comment: I have made above change in UPDATE query. So, try now and please let me know.

Comment: wrt your first question, only one record is returned for that trigger statement.

Comment: Then try the changed query now.

Comment: so you think its better to do the insert with the trigger?

Comment: No. You should not use trigger. A stored procedure is the best approach. Stored procedures are visible and when issues happen, its easy for a developer to see what's happening. A trigger on the other hand can cause hard to debug issues.

Comment: Ok then sorry one more question. When do I call this stored procedure then? Because the original insert is in a stored procedure and I am not sure I will be allowed to remove it.

Comment: Can you not change that existing stored procedure to what is given here?

Comment: If you can send me the original stored procedure in a chat room then I can put the necessary statements in that procedure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158842/discussion-between-vbnewbie-and-sunil).

Comment: Just changed the query for special insert.  Use this one.