# Restrict a bit field to true in only one child record at a time

Tags: sql-server

I have a `Person` table, each of who's records belongs to a parent record from the  `Company` table.

One `Person` is designated as "Organizer" for their parent `Company`. Initially I handled this by having a recursive reference from the `Company` table identifying the `Person` record that was it's "Organizer" - but the software I'm using to build my application layer falls over - it can't handle recursive references.

I've changed tack, and have added a bit field to the `Person` table to identify whether the person is an "Organizer" or not, but neet to ensure that there is only *one* "Organizer" for each `Company` record. If I use an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger on the Person table, an update on `Person` triggers an update on `Person` - obviously I want to avoid recursive triggers.

***How can I ensure that there is only ever one `Person` marked as the "Organizer" for it's parent `Company`?***

```
+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+                             +-----------+---------+---------+-----------+
| FirstName | Surname | Company | Organizer |                             | FirstName | Surname | Company | Organizer |
+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+                             +-----------+---------+---------+-----------+
| John      | Smith   |       1 | True      |                             | John      | Smith   |       1 | True      |
| Mike      | Jones   |       1 | NULL      |                             | Mike      | Jones   |       1 | NULL      |
| Fred      | Green   |       1 | NULL      |                             | Fred      | Green   |       1 | NULL      |
| James     | McMahon |       2 | NULL      |                             | James     | McMahon |       2 | NULL      |
| Philip    | Stills  |       2 | NULL      | Making Philip organizer ==> | Philip    | Stills  |       2 | True      |
| Hector    | Berlioz |       2 | True      | 'triggers' this change  ==> | Hector    | Berlioz |       2 | NULL      |
+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+                             +-----------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Unique index with where clause? For example, `create unique index ix_your_index_name on Person (Company, Organizer) where Organizer is not null`.

Comment: Probably not what you want, but have you thought about designating a `Organizer` Field in the Company table instead? That way you can store the information of who is an organizer there and fetch it via joins if necessary. Also, does your person table have a unique identifier number (something like ID?) if not, it should have that.

Comment: A unique index as already mentioned or a constraint with a udf like this for example: `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [chkUniqueOrganizer] CHECK  (([dbo].[CheckUniqueOrganizer](Company)=0))`

Comment: @Magisch yeah, there's an ID for each table, just didn't include it for simplicity of the example. Your suggestion is exactly what I originally did, but my client side software can't handle recursive references - that would essentially make the Company a child of one of it's own child records. Fine in SQL Server, but not in the application layer.

Comment: @user1711390 I don't quite follow... Perhaps if you fleshed that idea out in an answer?

Comment: i missed the part that you also want to remove the old organizer. i think thats not possible with my suggestion. But you can prevent recursion in triggers:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529412/how-do-i-prevent-a-database-trigger-from-recursing/47074365#47074365)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So seeing as no-one has given an answer here, I'll post what I eventually did:

Created a separate table called Organizer, with only two fields:

```
CREATE TABLE Organizer (
    Company int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Person int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Organizer_Company FOREIGN KEY (Company) REFERENCES Company(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Organizer_Person FOREIGN KEY (Person) REFERENCES Person(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Organizer_ID PRIMARY KEY (Company, Person)
);
```

- By making the `Company` field unique, I can only ever have one organizer for any company.
- `ON DELETE CASCADE` prevents me ending up with orphan organizer records for companies or people that don't exist.
- Can't quite recall why I made the `PRIMARY KEY` both fields. Doesn't seem to hurt.

It was then just a matter of checking for an existing `Organizer` record and updating that if it existed, or inserting one if it didn't. I did this in the application layer, though I could just have easily have made a Stored Procedure that took `Company.ID` and `Person.ID` parameters, checked for `Organizer` records with the former, and updated the table accordingly. Could even throw in a check for whether the Person actually belongs to that company, and return a value accordingly to the application layer.